Ubuntu 22.04 Perle IOLAN SDG4 driver
Has anyone successfully compiled the Perle TruePort driver under Ubuntu 22.04? Vendor acknowledges issue with compile and recommended I try the community for a faster solution.
dmoser@invariant-corp.net
Don
